# I have this function that is supposed to count points but it doesn't add them

Tags: python

I have this function that is supposed to count points but it doesn't add them:

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    print "Correct"
    totalPoints = totalPoints+1
    print "You have", totalPoints,"points"
```

Here is an example of what I use it in:

```
elif answer == 'nba':
        NBAQues = random.randint(0,len(NBA1)-1)

    NBAVar = NBA1[NBAQues]

    print NBAVar
    NBAAnswer = raw_input()
    NBAAnswer = NBAAnswer.lower()
    if NBAAnswer == NBA2[NBAQues]:
        print Correct(totalPoints)
    elif NBAAnswer != NBA2[NBAQues]:
        print "False. The correct answer was", NBA2[NBAQues]
        NBA1.remove(NBAVar)
        NBA2.remove(NBA2[NBAQues])
        print "Choose another."
```

Comment: Might want to fix the formatting for that first `elif answer`... line. It didn't make it into the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mix local and global namespaces. If you change your `Correct(totalPoints)` to this:

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    return totalPoints + 1
```

and in your "main code":

```
print Correct(totalPoints)
```

to

```
totalPoints = Correct(totalPoints)
print "You have", totalPoints, "points"
```

it should work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`totalPoints` is being cloned inside your function. To do what you want, you should set `totalPoints` based on the function result, like so:

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    print "Correct"
    totalPoints = totalPoints+1
    print "You have", totalPoints,"points"
    return totalPoints

totalPoints = Correct(totalPoints)
```

This ignores why you would want such a function in the first place, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need your `Correct` function to return something. Right now, you're printing a result and changing the `totalPoints` local variable (which got copied in when passed as an argument to the function). When you make that change to `totalPoints` inside of the `Correct` function, it's only changing the local, copies variable, not the one that was passed in.

Try this instead:

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    print "Correct"
    totalPoints = totalPoints+1
    print "You have", totalPoints,"points"
    return totalPoints
```

Now that it's returning the totalPoints, that variable can be brought back out to your regular program.

Answer (score 0):

1) you're not returning the value from the function
2) global variables are best changed outside of functions
  - outside of the function, set the variable equal to whatever the function returns or
  - if you MUST do it inside the function, you want to declare it to be global at the beginning of the function.

```
def Correct(totalpoints):
    return totalpoints += 1
```

......

```
if NBAANSWER == NBA2[NBAQues]:
    print "Correct!"
    totalpoints = Correct(totalPoints)
    print "You have ", totalpoints, "points"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

totalPoint must be declared as a global variable

and make the refernece in the function so python can update that value and not creating a new variable

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    global totalPoints
    print "Correct"
    totalPoints = totalPoints+1
    print "You have", totalPoints,"points"
```

Answer (score 0):

`totalPoints` is passed by value.  Which means a new copy is made and that copy is manipulated in the Correct function.  Since the modified totalPoints is never returned it is lost.  You need something like:

```
def Correct(totalPoints):
    return totalPoints += 1
```

and call it with

```
totalPoints = Correct(totalPoints)
```

The code doesn't show the original totalPoint definition, but that should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the function output. It should be

```
def Correct(mytotalPoints):
    print "Correct"
    mytotalPoints += 1
    print "You have", mytotalPoints,"points"
    return mytotalPoints
```

You should now return the correct value to the main function. You should also fix the indentation to be correct. You need to show where totalPoints was defined.

```
    elif answer == 'nba':
        NBAQues = random.randint(0,len(NBA1)-1)
    # Is this the way you meant it to be indented?
    NBAVar = NBA1[NBAQues]

    print NBAVar
    NBAAnswer = raw_input()
    NBAAnswer = NBAAnswer.lower()
    if NBAAnswer == NBA2[NBAQues]:
        # Make sure totalPoints was initialized properly
        totalPoints = Correct(totalPoints)
        print totalPoints
    elif NBAAnswer != NBA2[NBAQues]:
        print "False. The correct answer was", NBA2[NBAQues]
        NBA1.remove(NBAVar)
        NBA2.remove(NBA2[NBAQues])
        print "Choose another."
```

Comment: Two answers from you??

Comment: @linusg typo. was supposed to have been an edit. deleted one of the two.