# Writing a function to add points after points = 0

Tags: python, function

I am writing a function to find out how many points you earn. It is supposed to add the points to points but after when I print the points outside of the function, it says points = 0. Here is the function...

```
points = 0
def correct(points):
        if question >= 0 and question <= 3:
            points = points + 100
            print 'That was a 100 point question.'
        elif question >= 4 and question <= 7:
            points = points + 200
            print 'That was a 200 point question.'
        elif question >= 8 and question <= 11:
            points = points + 300
            print 'That was a 300 point question.'
        else: 
            points = points + 400
            print 'That was a 400 point question.'
        return points


Here is an example of the function in my code.

    if ranswer == random2[question]: #if you get it right
        correct(points)
        print 'Correct! You now have', points, 'points!'
```

In the end, it should print the amount of points I have but it prints 0.

Comment: Can you declare `points` before using it, means before first initialization?

Comment: Asked 20 minutes ago (same function name...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726609/i-have-this-function-that-is-supposed-to-count-points-but-it-doesnt-add-them/

Comment: @linusg I see that the code is different and the OP is different. Must have been a coincidence.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I was wondering. Isn't that often, that two questions (in 20 min) contain nearly the same code...

Comment: @linusg complete coincidence, I looked to see if there were any similar and must've missed this one. Sorry

Comment: The mistake is the same, mixing global and local variable namespaces.

Comment: @linusg , I don't know what to say it was a coincidence...

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `points` to return value from `correct(points)`.

`points = correct(points)`

Integers are immutable objects in Python. When you assign a new value to `points` inside `correct()`, it's not same as original `points` you had. Now it points to a different integer object. This is the reason you need to update `points` in calling code with returned value from `correct(points)`.

Comment: No copy is being made when `points` is passed into `correct()`.

Comment: Isn't `points` inside `correct()` a separate copy from `points` in calling code?

Comment: No. `points` is a pointer to an integer object and when you call a function, that pointer is passed into the function. (OK, the pointer is copied, but the integer value is not.) When you change `points` inside the function, it is made to point to a different integer object. This is the reason the value outside the function isn't changed; it still points to the original integer object.

Comment: Got it. I'll update the answer.